# Javascript function to not load in images from a Http-source

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and are trying to become better.

I was wondering how i can with the help och template-tag load the image in it if a Image is unsafe like from a http-source. Think of it like a email-client asking you if you want to load in images if not then it breaks the src. like src=temp-data, and when clicked to download and show the images then it sets the src to the correct one. here is the code i have written thus far

```js
function removeUnsafeImgLinks(bodyContent) {
  let _bodyContent = bodyContent
  const el = document.createElement('template');
  el.innerHTML = _bodyContent
  const nodes = el.querySelectorAll('img[src^="http://"]');
  if (nodes.length > 0) {
    nodes.forEach((x => {
      x.innerHTML.replace("src=temp-data")
    }));
  }
  iframe.srcdoc = el.innerHTML;
  return newBod;
}
```

Anyone got any tip or solution?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What exactly are you looking for? We can't help you like this. (And, personally, I'm not sure what you mean by "template-tag".)

Comment: Also what is `let _bodyContent = bodyContent`  supposed to do? They are both pointing to the same object

Comment: Also I expect you meant `nodes.forEach(x => x.src='temp-data')` because this does nothing `x.innerHTML.replace("src=temp-data")`

Comment: That `replace` call makes no sense. It's lacking the second argument and does nothing with the returned new string.

Comment: Well i am creating a function that is suppose to hide images that comes from a http:// source by breaking the src on those img-files and this img-files that comes from https:// are to be shown. and if the user want to see the unsafe image still, then i fix the src. And the reason i want to use template is there i can hold html that i dont want to render immediately. and the idea is to store those images there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Answer (score 1):

`x.innerHTML.replace("src=temp-data")` does not actually change anything

Fixing your syntax errors you might mean

```js
const removeUnsafeImgLinks = bodyContent => {
  const el = document.createElement('template');
  el.innerHTML = bodyContent
  const imgs = [...el.querySelectorAll('img[src^="http://"]')];
  if (imgs.length>0) {
    imgs.forEach(x => x.src='temp-data')
    iframe.srcdoc = el.innerHTML;
  }
};
```